# No resource identifier found for attribute 'menu' in package in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

No resource identifier found for attribute 'menu' in package in Android:

I'm getting this error in my layout xml file. I have the following libraries:
`android-support-v4.jar` and `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` in my project folder.

(Using Eclipse)

Here is my XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"
    />
```

Build.Gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

PS: I'm using Eclipse Mars and I'm experiencing a lot of problems with building and importing external libraries. It's been way too much of a hassle so I'm thinking of switching to Android Studio. Please leave me any helpful advice with regards to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up switching to Android Studio which fixed the problem. Eclipse seems to have a lot of bugs when trying to add support libraries.